# Radio button not appearing

Tags: visualforce, radio-button

Drastically updated code/this question after getting more understanding. I think it would be best to use a checkbox for this field rather than radio button, and the issue seems to be dependent on the field in a way I cannot understand.

I have a field on cs (case, created in controller) that takes a boolean value. It is a checkbox. I have the following...

```
<apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value=" 
                {!cs.thisProduct}"/>
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
```

When I changed it from determining the value to cs.someOtherField, it shows up! Great. But when I change it back to thisProduct, it doesn't show at all. This page is public on a Site, and for testing, I've made this field viewable by all profiles. Why is it disappearing?

Other fields on this page map to the 'cs' case object fine, and I tried making a product = {get;set} variable for this and doing cs.thisProduct = product in the controller, no luck. How should I go about this?

Sorry if this is changed too much for 1 post; I'm just figuring out better practice as I go

Comment: Please include the controller code populating these properties. Because both sections are rendering, the issue probably is not the Boolean but something to do with the select options or with what sounds like a partial page rerender.

Comment: Cleaned it up a bit -- found out more about how the options are set b/w VF and the controller....

Comment: For what it's worth, without the text there or anything, the page still looks like it *makes room for the radio field* by itself when I add it and remove it and watch the link next to it shift around...but it doesn't show...

Comment: What does the `cs` and its corresponding property/method `controllerVal` from `{!cs.controllerVal}` look like? Try adding debug statements to `controllerVal` to show if it is being called.

Comment: This is definitely not the issue. cs.controllerVal just refers to an object's field (a Case) that is going to take the value of the radio button (checked or unchecked) and the radio button's appearance doesn't depend on this part...nothing is being "invoked" by that, it's just saying "this is what the value of the button will be".

Comment: The block that the radio button is in *is* 100% being rendered, because the text next to it in the same block appears. I use the standard <apex:selectOptions value="!Items"> and corresponding "getItems" function in the controller as per the documentation (diff. variable names, but for the sake of describing it, I keep it generic here) so I don't know why it's not showing up

Comment: Hi Natalie - can you post how have you declared cs.controllerVal in the apex? The value attribute should map directly to a controller variable. If you may have it mapped to an object's field, I doubt if that's causing the issue.

Comment: cs = new Case();  is in the controller. This is not the issue whatsoever, because every other field in this form has the exact same way of mapping the VF field to this object. However, the issue may have to do with the field itself, because my checkbox (tested instead of radio button) shows up fine when it uses a different field on the cs object. This is a public page on a site and I made permissions on this field to be accessible by all profiles for the sake of testing

Comment: wait, do I need to do {get;set;} ?

Answer (score -1):

It was permissions! After I tested it with other fields and it worked, I figured it had to do with that, but this page is public and I didn't know about the guest access permissions. Thank you to all who contributed!!!